# How to delete flask filter object at once?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my code currently

```
check = request.form.getlist('checkbox')
pprint.pprint(check) # [u'3', u'2']
check_obj = Todo.query.filter(Todo.id.in_(check))
db.session.delete(check_obj)
db.session.commit()
```

But this rise `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError`. So how do i delete multiple object at once

Answer (score 1):

You can replace 4 line with smth like this:

```
for item in check_obj:
    db.session.delete(item)
```